# Incorrect output using array as counter

Tags: c++, arrays, counter

I'm trying to teach myself programming by attempting problems from codeabbey.com.

I'm not getting the correct output on [this question](http://www.codeabbey.com/index/task_view/array-counters).

> **Question:**
> Here is an array of length M with numbers in the range 1 ... N, where N is less than or equal to 20. You are to go through it and count how many times each number is encountered.
>
> Input data contain M and N in the first line.
> The second (rather long) line will contain M numbers separated by spaces.
> Answer should contain exactly N values, separated by spaces. First should give amount of 1-s, second - amount of 2-s and so on.

**Data input:**

> 10 3
>
> 1 2 3 2 3 1 1 1 1 3

**Correct Output:**

> 5 2 3

**My Output:**

> 7 3 4

You can check [here](http://ideone.com/oc0mQT)

**My Code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int arrayLength,range,a;
    cin>>arrayLength>>range;
    int array[20];
    array[20]={0};
    
    for(int i=0; i<arrayLength; i++)
    {   
        cin>>a;
        ++array[a-1];
    }
    for(a=0; a<range; a++)
    {   
    cout<<array[a]<<" ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There aren't any error messages or warnings. Also, if you have any suggestions for improving the code, that'd be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int array[20];
array[20]={0};
```

is wrong, since it leave the array un-initialized and tries to initialize the 21st element (which is undefined behaviour btw, since your array has only 20 elements, remember that indexing starts from `0`). Use

```
int array[20] = {0}; // this will initialize all elements to 0
```

and your code will work as expected. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) for more details regarding aggregate initialization in C++.

Answer (score 1):

`array[20]={0};` initializes the 21st element(non-existing) to `0`.
So you have to use `int array[20] = {0};` which will initialize all 20 elements to zero.

Also from your code, you are not storing the elements to an array. You are just incrementing the corresponding count when an input is read. If so, what is the need of initializing an array to max limit. Just declare the array as you need it. In your case,

`int array[range] = {0};`

It will initialize an array of three (range =3 here) elements.